# QGIS 3 - applying the same selection polygon to other layer

Tags: qgis, layers, select

I have selected my large layer by using the "Select by polygon" option.
Unfortunately, I don't know how I could apply exactly the same polygon to another layer, which applies pretty much to the same area.
Is it possible? I use the 3.12 version so far.

[image]

Comment: I would create a temp layer and digitize a polygon then use this to select by location. That way you can reuse the polygon multiple times